# elasticsearch mongoid filter on has_many ids

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, mongoid

I'm using ES 1.4, Rails 5, and Mongoid 6. I'm also the mongoid-elasticsearch gem, which I don't think is relevant, but including it in case I'm wrong.

I have a Case model.  When I run this query, everything works great, here's the query:

```
GET _search
{
   "query":{
      "filtered":{
         "query":{
            "query_string":{
               "query":"behemoth"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Here's a result, notice the organization_id:

```
hits": [
        {
           "_index": "cases",
           "_type": "case",
           "_id": "57d5e583a46100386987d7f4",
           "_score": 0.13424811,
           "_source": {
              "basic info": {
                 "first name": "Joe",
                 "last name": "Smith",
                 "narrative": "behemoth"
              },
              "organization_id": {
                 "$oid": "57d4bc2fa461003841507f83"
              },
              "case_type_id": {
                 "$oid": "57d4bc7aa461002854f88441"
              }
           }
        }
```

See how there's that "$oid" for organzation id? That's because in my as_indexed_json method for Case, I have:

```
["organization_id"] = self.case_type.organization.id
```

I think that the filter doesn't work b/c Mongoid somehow adds that subkey $oid. So my next thought was, I'll just make it a string:

```
["organization_id"] = self.case_type.organization.id.to_s
```

But that throws an error:

```
{"error":"MapperParsingException[object mapping for [case] tried to parse as object, but got EOF, has a concrete value been provided to it?]","status":400}
```

Anyone have any idea how to A) either use a mongo id as a filter, or B) get ES the info it needs so it doesn't complain as above?

Thanks for any help,
Kevin

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that this is because there was already an existing index.  When I nuked the index and re-indexed the data, this works fine (really bad error syntax with ES).